# Gnome 3.28.2 always showing 'VPN OFF'

Tags: vpn, gnome, networkmanager

I'm using Debian with Gnome 3.28.2

I've been using my VPN with no problems but Gnome will always display 'VPN Off' even when the VPN is active.

[image: Screenshot showing VPN status]

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

I haven't found anything on the Debian wiki about this and I apologize if I missed a topic that covers this issue.

Comment: i have the same problem on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed on next gnome 3.28 and latest 3.30.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/140